# Port not getting forwarded correctly even though a DynDNS hostname is created

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

## Dynamic IP-address is not able to be forwarded correctly

Hi guys

I've recently discovered an odd problem. When I'm at my own house (with a static IP) my **Team Fortress 2**-dedicated server is working just fine. But when I'm at my girlfriends house (with a dynamic IP) it's not running even when the ports are forwarded. I did some research and discovered that you need a *hostname.* I created one free at [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com) and downloaded their **Update Client.** When I forward the ports on my Linksys WRT54G, I am only able to select the port(s) to be forwarded, the protocol and the **ending digit (max 2 cifres) of the IP** and not the whole IP. Ie it says "192.168.1.[*this is what I can enter*]".

If I open CMD and type in `ipconfig` it tells me that my IP-address (IPv4) is `192.168.1.18` but if I go to [PortForward](http://www.portforward.com/) it tells me that `Your external IP is 85.81.157.93`

When I open TF2 and type in `connect 192.168.1.18:27015` I am able to join and so are other people on this very wireless network. But it's not able to connect when I type in `connect myddns-example.dyndns-server.com:27015 or connect 85.81.157.93:27015`. Have any of you experienced the same problem, and if so, can any of you help me figure this out? I'm probably, I mean **obviously**, doing something wrong :)

Many of you must think "what a retard, I'm not answering this" but respect to the few wanting to answer such a probably stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I recommend the [DynDNS Community](http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/) for DynDNS related questions.  There you'll even find [a guide](http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/questions/16/how-do-i-access-my-device-from-outside-my-home-network) to port forwarding and testing, which should walk you through what you need to do.

In your case you want to forward the TF2 ports to `192.168.1.18`, from your WRT54G (assuming you don't have an ADSL modem).  Simply creating a DynDNS hostname, or running an update client, doesn't forward any ports.

Comment: Thank you, i actually didnt know they had a forum :) thanks